# Collecting RSS Feeds Online?

Tags: rss, feed

I'd like to be able to collect RSS feeds online as an alternative to collecting them on a desktop machine using a regularly running process.

Ideally, it would either collect all feeds and simply email them to a single address as soon as it finds a new one (or even without checking for new feeds) or aggregates all the smaller feeds and sends them out as a bulk larger feed less periodically.

It would have to run on a web server continually, but would be a nice to be able to collect all feeds, not just the ones I happen to pick up when a feed reader is running on my machine. Is something like this available?

Comment: Why not just use an online tool like [Google Reader](https://www.google.com/reader)?

Comment: Great, that'll do the job perfectly. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Not really sure how this is programming related though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Reader](https://www.google.com/reader).

Answer (score 3):

Just use Google Reader. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Yahoo's Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) could help you. It is an interesting way of combining and manipulating feeds.

Comment: +1 I like Yahoo's Pipes, nobody seems to know about that one either. Of course, for his (Dan's) needs, wget may be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have ever used it but iGoogle allows you to customise the google homepage to display information from around the web. You can add tabs to the page to allow you to split the information up. It's extremely useful and as you can log into it from any computer / browser you can access your feeds anywhere.

If you have a lot of feeds of one type or feeds that update infrequently then iGoogle can also be combined with google reader.

It's also great for adding other plugins like gmail, games, Dilbert :) and more.

To create an iGoogle page go to the google home page and click the iGoogle link in the top right corner. iGoogle will then provide you with a starter page and some suggested content which you can add or ignore. If you click the "Add Stuff" link then "Add feed or gadget" you can manually add all your RSS feeds. However, you can also configure Firefox to automatically select google as your RSS reader when ever you click on an RSS feed icon in the navigation bar. You can select / change this under Tools -> Options -> Applications -> Web Feed.

In order to use your iGoogle on multiple browsers / computers you will need a gmail / google account however it's free and easy to create.

T

Answer (score 0):

[simplepie](http://simplepie.org/) is great if you have PHP installed.

Answer (score 0):

[Universal Feed Parser](http://www.feedparser.org/) if you're programming in python might be of help